# Q-pigeon hole: a group of 52 sequences, each 9 long from the group {0,1}

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

let A be a group of sequences, each sequence length is 9 and each od its elements is from the group {0,1}
we know that |A| =52.
show that there exsits at least 2 sequence a1 and a2 such that you can switch at most 2 elemnts in a1 and get a2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume that you meant “switch *at most* $2$ elements”, since the statement is false as written.

Around each sequence is a ball of $10$ sequences that differ from it in at most $1$ element. If there were no two sequences at distance at most $2$, these balls could not overlap. There would be $10\cdot52=520$ different sequences in these balls, but there are only $2^9=512$ different binary sequences of length $9$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Indeed I was, thanks!

Comment: yes i ment at most thank you, could you eaplain what do you mean when you say: "each sequence is a ball of 10 sequences". i didnt really understood your answer

Comment: @RoiHezkiyahu: That seems to be a language issue. It's not "each sequence is a ball of $10$ sequences"; the word "around" before that is also part of that phrase: "Around each sequence is a ball of $10$ sequences". So each sequence is surrounded by a ball of $10$ sequences that differ from in it at most $1$ element. For a binary sequence of length $9$, there are $9$ positions in which you change $1$ bit, and thus $9$ sequences that differ from the sequence in exactly one position. The $10$th sequence is the sequence itself, which differs from itself in $0$ and thus also at most $1$ position.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot!